# How to pass the model matrix off to the shader and make the triangle rotate

Tags: opengl, glm-math

I am using OpenGL and GLM library, and I try to pass the model matrix off to the shader and make the triangle rotate. I have already got the basic code and getting the IDs of the variables in the vertex shader. While I have no idea how to actually setting them.

```
    #include <GL/GLEW.h>
    #include <GL/freeglut.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    #include <glm/vec3.hpp> // glm::vec3
    #include <glm/vec4.hpp> // glm::vec4
    #include <glm/mat4x4.hpp> // glm::mat4
    #include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp> // glm::translate/rotate/scale/etc
    #include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp> // glm::value_ptr



    #define BUFFER_OFFSET(i) ((char *)NULL + (i))

    glm::mat4 M;
    glm::mat4 V;
    glm::mat4 P;
    glm::mat4 trans;
    glm::mat4 rot;
    float rotAmount = 0.0f;

    GLint umM;
    GLint umV;
    GLint umP;

    void func(GLuint LocationMVP, float Translate, glm::vec2 const & Rotate)
    {
        glm::mat4 Projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 100.f);
        glm::mat4 ViewTranslate = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -Translate));
        glm::mat4 ViewRotateX = glm::rotate(ViewTranslate, Rotate.y, glm::vec3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        glm::mat4 View = glm::rotate(ViewRotateX, Rotate.x, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
        glm::mat4 Model = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.5f));
        glm::mat4 MVP = Projection * View * Model;
        glUniformMatrix4fv(LocationMVP, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(MVP));
    }

    void render() 
    {

        trans = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0, 0, -1));
        rot = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), rotAmount, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
        M = trans*rot;

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 9, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);
        glutSwapBuffers();
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }

    void specialKeys(int key, int x, int y) {
        switch (key) {
        case GLUT_KEY_UP: printf("The UP key was pressed\n"); break;
        case GLUT_KEY_DOWN: printf("The DOWN key was pressed\n"); break;
        }
    }

    void mousePressed(int button, int state, int x, int y) 
    {
        if ((button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON) && (state == GLUT_DOWN)) {
            //printf("Mouse clicked at %d %d\n", x, y);
        }
    }

    void mouseMoved(int x, int y) {
        //printf("Mouse moved at %d %d\n", x, y);
    }

    void mouseDragged(int x, int y) {
        //printf("Mouse dragged at %d %d\n", x, y);
    }



    int main(int argc, char** argv) 
    {


        glutInit(&argc, argv);              // Initialize GLUT
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA); // Set up buffers
        glutInitWindowPosition(200, 200);   // Optional: position the upper-left of the window
        glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);       // Set the window size
        glutCreateWindow("Lab 5");          // Create the window and give it a title

        glewInit();                         // Ask the driver for all the OpenGL functions

        // Some callback functions
        glutDisplayFunc(render);            // Use the render function to draw
        glutSpecialFunc(specialKeys);       // Use the specialKeys function for Up/Down/Left/Right keys
        glutMouseFunc(mousePressed);        // Use for mouse clicks
        glutMotionFunc(mouseDragged);       // Use for mouse dragging
        glutPassiveMotionFunc(mouseMoved); // Use for mouse moving

    #pragma region SHADER_STUFF
        // =========  SHADER STUFF  ===============
        const GLchar* vertexShaderCode = "#version 150\n\
                                in vec4 vPosition;\n\
                                in vec4 vColor;\n\
                                out vec4 color;\n\
                                void main () {\n\
                                    color = vColor;\n\
                                    \tgl_Position = vPosition;\n\
                                 }\n";

const GLchar* fragmentShaderCode = "#version 150\n\n\
                                    out vec4 fColor;\n\
                                    in vec4 color;\n\
                                    void main () {\
                                       fColor = color;\n\
                                    }";
        // Vertex Shader 
        GLint vertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertexShaderID, 1, &vertexShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vertexShaderID);
        GLint compiled = -10;
        glGetShaderiv(vertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled);
        printf("Vertex compile status %d!\n", compiled);
        printf("Vertex shader ID is %d\n", vertexShaderID);

        // Fragment Shader 
        GLint fragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragmentShaderID, 1, &fragmentShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragmentShaderID);
        GLint compiled2 = -19;
     glGetShaderiv(fragmentShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compiled2);

        printf("Fragment compile status %d!\n", compiled2);
        printf("Fragment shader ID is %d\n", fragmentShaderID);

        // Make the program
        GLint shaderProgram;
        shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShaderID);
        glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShaderID);
        glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
        GLint linkedStatus = 14;
        glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkedStatus);
        printf("Link status is %d\n", linkedStatus);
        printf("Shader program ID is %d\n", shaderProgram);

        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    #pragma endregion SHADER_STUFF

        // Positions
        GLfloat vertices[] = { -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // 0
            -0.25f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // 1
            0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, // 2
            0.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // 3
            0.25f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // 4
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // 5
        };

        // Color information
        GLfloat colors[] = { 1.0f, 0.73f, 0.0f, 1.0f, //0
            1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // 1
            1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // 2
            1.0f, 0.73f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // 3
            1.0f, 0.65f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // 4
            1.0f, 0.65f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // 5
        };

        // Connect the dots
        GLuint index_buffer[] = { 0, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 4, 3, 5 };

        int numVertices = 6;

        GLuint vao;
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
        glBindVertexArray(vao); // Use the Vertex Array Object we created above

        GLuint vbo;     // The Vertex Buffer Object ID
        glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);  // Ask the GPU driver for a buffer array. "vbo" now has the ID
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo); // Make this buffer the active one for subsequent operations (below)

        // Specify how big the buffer is, but don't pass the data yet (see NULL).  We *could* have, but I wanted to show glBufferSubData
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, numVertices * 7 * sizeof(GLfloat), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        // NOW we copy the data in as a separate step. There is an "offset" of 0 - meaning the beginning of the buffer. 
        // We specify the size of the data we want to copy, followed by a pointer to the actual data
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, numVertices * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), vertices);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, numVertices * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), numVertices * 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), colors);

        // Figure out where vPosition is in our shader and get its ID
        GLuint loc = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "vPosition");
        GLuint loc2 = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "vColor");
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc2);

        printf("vPosition ID is %d\n", loc);
        printf("vColor ID is %d\n", loc2);

        // When it's time for vPosition to find information, we need to tell it where the data is (or how the data should be parsed)
        // Here, we're saying that "vPosition" (loc from above) should look for 3 GLfloats. The data isn't normalized or interlaced, 
        // and starts at index 0 (the beginning of the current buffer)
        glVertexAttribPointer(loc, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(loc2, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,         BUFFER_OFFSET(numVertices * 3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));


        GLuint index_vbo;
        // Ask the graphics card (driver) for another buffer – same as the old code
        glGenBuffers(1, &index_vbo);
        // We still want the VAO active to remember these settings
        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        // Here's where we tell the driver that it's an index buffer.  
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index_vbo);
        // This time, we'll just go ahead and pass the data off to the buffer because
        // we're not packing multiple data sets into the buffer - only indices

        umM = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "mM"); // Find the mM variable
        umV = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "mV"); // Find the mV variable
        umP = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "mP"); // Find the mP variable

        if (umP != -1)
        {
    glUniformMatrix4fv(umP, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(P));
     }
        if (umV != -1)
        {
            glUniformMatrix4fv(umV, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(V));
        }

        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 9*sizeof(GLuint), index_buffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        P = glm::perspective(-60.0f, 1.3f, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
        V = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0, 0, 0));

        glm::mat4 T = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        glm::mat4 Rx = glm::rotate(T, rotation_x, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        glm::mat4 Ry = glm::rotate(Rx, rotation_y, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
        glm::mat4 M = glm::rotate(Ry, rotation_z, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
        glm::mat4 MVP = P*V*M;

        glutMainLoop();                     // Start listening for events
    }
```

and also my shader file is like

```
    #version 150
    in vec4 vPosition;
    uniform mat4 mM; // The matrix for the pose of the model
    uniform mat4 mV; // The matrix for the pose of the camera
    uniform mat4 mP; // The perspective matrix

    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = mP*mV*mM*vPosition;


    }
```

Could any one help me, or teach me how to setting them?

Comment: You're using hard coded shader strings and not actually loading the shader file, which contains code that belongs on the OpenGL program. You need to get the uniform locations in the OpenGL program, not in the shader program. I'd say that if you're writing OpenGL code in the shaders you should find a good tutorial. It's hard to answer given how many things are wrong/missing in your code.

Comment: I see, thank you so much~